# Storing python script return value to bash shell in a jenkins job

Tags: python, bash, jenkins

I have a python script `a.py` that returns a tuple of two values.
I am running this script from a Jenkins bash shell and I need to be able to retrieve the return values and use them in the further steps of the job.

As of now, the call to the script looks like:

```
ret_tuple=($($ENV_PATH/bin/python a.py))
```

Then I am trying to access the return value and assign it to variables that later I would inject into the Jenkins job

```
echo "${ret_tuple[0]}"
echo "${ret_tuple[1]}"

echo SRC_BUCKET=${ret_tuple[0]} > variables.properties
echo DST_BUCKET=${ret_tuple[1]} > variables.properties
```

Later, I forward these variables into another job that this job triggers and I can see that the parameters that are being sent from the variables are incorrect.
One of them holds `$SRC_BUCKET` and the second one `Disabled!` (which doesn't make a lot of sense to me).
I pass the variables like that:

```
data_path=${SRC_BUCKET}
destination_path=${DST_BUCKET}
```

Am I doing this in the right way and I should look for the problem in another place? or there's something wrong with this variable assignment above?

EDIT:
The python script returns two strings

```
src_bucket_path = os.path.join(export_path, file_name)
dst_bucket_path = os.path.join(destination_path, dst_bucket_suffix_path)
return src_bucket_path, dst_bucket_path
```

Comment: if the error appears when you "later forward these variables into another job", then you really need to give us more context on how these variables are passed.

Comment: and do you get a literal `$SRC_BUCKET` or the value of `SRC_BUCKET`? and if you get a literal `Disabled!`, then you have left out some crucial bit of code in your question.

Comment: @umläute Does my edit help?
I already specified in the original question how these variables are passed - triggering another job and passing predefined parameters

Comment: hmm, no not really. i was more concerned about what you do *later*.
however: you cannot `return` things from a python-script like this. typically you would print the results to stdout (within the python script), and catch it with `$()` (in bash)

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example on how to create a minimal reproducible example from which to work on

Comment: Assuming I use `print` instead of `return`, what other stuff I would have to change?
probably I would have to `| tail -n 2` to the script call. 
The assignment part should be ok?

Comment: I would suggest create a string out of the two return values using a separator in between and print it. Once you have the value in the bash variable, use awk or sed to split it back using the same separator and assign to 2 variables . Finally use those variables to call the other jobs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use command expansion, so the command is evaluated before outputted into the variables.properties files.

```
$(echo SRC_BUCKET=${ret_tuple[0]} > variables.properties)
$(echo DST_BUCKET=${ret_tuple[1]} > variables.properties)
```

A good article for you to read,
http://www.compciv.org/topics/bash/variables-and-substitution/

If you run your scripts in the same shell session window, you could create an environment variable from one script, and then when you run the next script you can access the environment variable.